# Multiple Tables vs Composite Key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've researched everywhere but rarely are there any discussions on the use of multiple DynamoDB tables. So I hope someone can shed some light regarding this.
Consider the following scenario:

The database has to store the user's books and the user's comics.

Most common access pattern is to get/put a single book, get/put a single comic, and query the entire collection of books or comics.

**Which of the following design is better?**

### Case 1: Using multiple tables (one for books, one for comics)

**BooksTable**

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: BookId1}

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: BookId2}

**ComicsTable**

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: ComicId1}

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: ComicId2}

To get or put a single book you do a get or put on BooksTable with full key {UserId, BookId1}
To get all user's books you do a query on BooksTable with {UserId}

### Case 2: Using composite sort keys (TYPE#ID)

**SharedTable**

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: BOOK#BookId1},

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: BOOK#BookId2},

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: COMIC#ComicId1},

{PartKey: UserId, SortKey: COMIC#ComicId2}

To get or put a single book you do a get or put with full key {UserId, BOOK#BookId}
To get all user's books you do a query with {UserId} with SortKey condition Starts_With(BOOK#)

**What is the correct choice here?**